# Datatables source populate

Tags: datatables

I am trying to show results from object nested results to jQuery Datatables

Also on each search i must refresh header values by users search dates(between)

But all known methods failed
Here screenshot of data and header values

How to populate object nested output on datatable?
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVyKM.jpg)

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, and the screenshot is unreadable. You can [edit] your question to show your code and data _as formatted text_ (not as a screenshot). You can also clarify what "all known methods failed" means. What methods are you referring to? Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: My best guess is that you are trying to do what is described here: [Nested object data](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep).